# Graph api using search and orderby at sametime

Tags: email, microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am currently working on getting maillist with orderby = receivedDateTime asc and search = 'keyword. I tested,
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$orderby=receivedDateTime asc&$search=keyword`

but I got response :
    `"error": { "code": "SearchWithOrderBy", "message": "The query parameter '$orderBy' is not supported with '$search'." }`

I working on changing EWS api to Graph api rn. I think this is critical issue.
Anyone know better to solve this?

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$orderby=receivedDateTime asc&$search=keyword`

Comment: Searching messages doesn't not support ordering. Even the Search API doesn't support sorting for messages. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-messages. Is it possible to use filter instead of search in your case?